# Virtualizing .NET framework

Tags: .net, deployment, virtualization, visual-studio-2012

I have a .NET 4.0 based Winform application which I virtualized using Spoon Virtual Application Studio 2012.

When I built the application using VS 2010 the final virtualized application ran fine, but if I build the application using VS 2012 and built the virtualized application then `System.Core file not found error` comes (both 4.0.0.0 and 3.5.0.0).

I guess the reason might be in VS 2010 `System.Core` was referenced as
 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll"`
whereas in VS 2012 the reference is
 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"`.
I am not sure.

Please help me how to fix this or what other software is there that can virtualize .NET Framework so that I can ship my application to client without the need to install .NET Framework.

Comment: Spoon is the best :) Did You try their support ? I've found it quite helpful for myself. there's an alternative from VMware - thinapp, but few years ago it did produce me a package 10x larger than the Spoon.

Comment: Ya the error came from spoon only. VS 2010 built assembly is fine but vs 2012 built assembly is producing the mentioned problem while trying to build with Spoon. I have raised an issue at their support, will let you knw if I get any reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the DotNet 4.0 .svm files yourself using Spoon snapshot method on a clean machine. Actually DotNet 4.0 svm are shipped with Spoon but as you are using VS2012 it must have upgraded DotNet 4 in some way. This might be the reason of file not found error because Spoon uses isolated file system and that's why host system file is not visible to the application.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have a clean machine. Has anybody tried to build dotnet 4 svm after vs 2012 installation?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup some VM using VirtualBox or similar and a Windows DVD to get a clean Windows installation. After installing and virtualizing your application you could reset your VM to the previous clean state and virtualize the next application.